# blender 2.82 can't unfold collection collection collection

Tags: actions

os10.13.6
Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB

When I clic on the collection , there is no unfold.
And same thing with a new collection, already unfold, it can't be fold…

please tell me I'm missing a new function :)

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the little triangle icon in front of the collections name?

Comment: Hello Robert, yes exactly on the triangle. Only the check box is working normally. Via ctrl I can enable the inside of the collection. But impossible to unfold… It seems to be a very specific bug only for me

Comment: Does it work when you select a collection and press Numpad +?

Comment: Oh yes, well done Sir!!! I can breath !!!!!

Comment: The UI button should still work anyway. Have you edited the preferences, keymap or installed add-ons? Something might interfere with the UI, similar to reports in [T69657](https://developer.blender.org/T69657) or [T68798](https://developer.blender.org/T68798).

Comment: Ok, you right, I imported at the very first time my keymap from 2.8 - Now I reset to the blender original keymap, and everything is normal. Thank again !!!!